# Switch navigation tabs manually in Navigation drawer in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, navigationbar

I am using latest Lollipop style Navigation drawer in my app.Please refer to [this example](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/) for more info on that.I use Fragments to show different navigation tabs. Now, I need to open, let's say the 5th item in drawer when I click a certain notification from the notification bar in android device. I am stuck in as to how to switch directly to that Fragment by clicking notification. I  am very much aware as how this can be done using Activity. Can anyone please suggest me any solution regarding this ?

Thanks in Advance.

Resolved:

I have resolved this issue by following Ziem's answer. I have just added following lines to open it as a new screen and clear older activity stack:

```
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `PendingIntent` to notification's [click](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#click):

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent;

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    ...
    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Next you need to handle notification's `Intent` inside your activity.

Example:

```
// How to create notification with Intent:
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
resultIntent.putExtra("open", 1);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!")
        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

int mNotificationId = 33;
NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());


//How to handle notification's Intent:
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().hasExtra("open")) {
            int fragmentIndexToOpen = getIntent().getIntExtra("open", -1)
            // show your fragment
        }
    }
}
```